# Integrating multiple C++ programs

Tags: c++, integration

So this may be vauge but hold on and see if you can understand what I am trying to get here.

A few months ago I created a spades card game (in C++) using card.cpp, card.h, player.cpp player.h, display.h and display.cpp.

Along side myself, another one of my class mates created a hearts card game (in C++) that also used card.cpp, card.h, player.cpp player.h, display.h, display.cpp as well as hearts.cpp, and hearts.h.

I'm trying to integrate these two programs together as well as add some more features such as shared scoring, but I really don't have a direction to go in.

I made both games objects so from my main.cpp file I can call them both to start them, but the problem I am running into is that the display classes have the same exact functions with slightly tweeked code inside them.(The player and card are totally different just same names) So I can't just use one display.cpp.

I am just looking for some slight guidance as to how to go about doing this.....

Thank you!

Also my directories look like the following

```
/proj2/Makefile
/proj2/main.cpp
/proj2/hearts/hearts.cpp
/proj2/hearts/display.cpp
/proj2/hearts/player.cpp
/proj2/hearts/card.cpp
/proj2/spades/spades.cpp
/proj2/spades/display.cpp
/proj2/spades/player.cpp
/proj2/spades/card.cpp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the declarations and definitions into separate namespaces should help.

You could put

```
namespace hearts {
  /* declarations/definitions from the hearts game */
}
```

around the declarations and definitions in all .h and .cpp files (but not including the `#include` statements) belonging to the hearts game, and

```
namespace spades {
  /* declarations/definitions from the spades game */
}
```

around the declarations and definitions (not including the `#include` statements) of the other game.

In a main.cpp that includes the headers from both, you can then refer to the individual types and functions as

```
hearts::player p;
spades::function();
```

and so on.

Comment: … of course sources and classes common to both games can go without a `namespace` or you can add `namespace cards {}` or such.

Comment: After doing this I am now getting an unusual error. error: expected type-specifier before 'Card'. It's refering to this line in my code,         hand[chosenIndex]=NULLCARD; hand[] is defined back in my player.cpp where I am using the hearts namespace! I tried defining hand both using hearts::Card hand[13]; and just Card hand[13]. I thought maybe it has to do with us being in the namespace and I am refering to Card which is in the same namespace?

Comment: @PeterBlum Why don't we discuss this here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20221/question-13598408

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the answers above have suggested how to change the code to remove naming clashes.

That is an option, of course, but suppose you have 2 sets of code built into DLLs (or shared objects) and you want to be able to work with both of them, i.e. load a game from an external application, without modifying any source.

The answer is to use dynamic library loading, and this is an advantage in other ways too. In UNIX systems you use `dlopen()` to open the library, either specifying the full path or a path visible relative to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. On Windows systems the call is LoadLibrary().

In UNIX you then load exported symbols (if using gnu's visibility hidden attributes, this would be specifically marked symbols, if visibility is default then by default symbols are exported unless specifically marked otherwise), using `dlsym`. In Windows symbols are normally exported either through a .def file or with `__declspec(dllexport)` and are loaded through `GetProcAddress`

To do this, you need to make your games "pluggable" into the system, but you have the huge advantage this way in that you can add more games later simply by writing a new library for it as a pluggable game, and can then load it into your games engine as a plug-in.

Of course your games can share common libraries. For example a hearts and spades game are likely to share the concept of a pack of cards as well as the fact they are both whist-related games so there is a concept of following suit and taking tricks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way do deal with naming conflict is to use namespaces.